# How to replace a double quote with a backwards slash preceded by a double quote

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to send a HTML file via through the payload of a HTTP request in Python.

If I pass the following HTML file then there are no problems as long as I remove the `\n` and `\t` characters.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1>My First Heading</h1>
            <p>My first paragraph.</p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

However, if I include any tags that have double quotes (e.g. `<img src="w3schools.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com" width="104" height="142">`) then the HTML breaks the JSON format of the payload that I am sending and my request to the server returns a 404.

My payload currently looks something like this:

`payload = f'{{"foo":"","bar":[],"html":"{html_file}"}}'.encode('utf-8')`

I need my HTML to look like this for it to be processed properly:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1>My First Heading</h1>
            <p>My first paragraph.</p>
            <img src=\"w3schools.jpg\" alt=\"W3Schools.com\" width=\"104\" height=\"142\">
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to hand craft your JSON. You could build a python `dict` and use the `json` module to do the encoding. Quotes, newlines and any other troublesome characters will get the proper escaping.

```
import json
html_file = """<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1>My First Heading</h1>
            <p>My first paragraph.</p>
            <img src="w3schools.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com" width="104" height="142">
        </body>
    </html>"""

payload = json.dumps({"foo":"","bar":[],"html":html_file}).encode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to do the quoting yourself. Python has a [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module for producing valid json, and it does all the right quoting for you. Use that!